# php get file folder name from url

Tags: php

I need get  file folder name from url

```
 examples: 
 http://domain/folder/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml
 http://domain/folder/folder2/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml
 http://domain/folder/folder2/folderanother/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml
```

I need only "NEEDTHIS" folder name only
i using this code for get file name

```
 $parts = parse_url("http://domain/folder/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml");  
            $title = basename($parts['path']);  
echo $title;
// Output: filename.xml
```

How can i get this file name folder?

Comment: try explode and point the second to the last key

Comment: What did you try? Have you ever tried to `explode()` ?

Comment: substr. Check the last occurence of / , substring to that index and redo another check for the last occurence (based on substring), that will obtain needthis

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you can even avoid parse_url()...:

```
$url = "http://domain/folder/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml";

$items = explode('/', $url);
echo $items[sizeof($items) - 2];
// Output: NEEDTHIS
```

Note: this solution only assumes directories/filenames are separated by a character. To be even more general, you could use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`:

```
$url = "http://domain/folder/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml";
$items = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $url);
echo $items[sizeof($items) - 2];
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is plain wrong in this case. If you are targeting URLs, the separator is / and not the filesystem separator. If DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is "\" your example would not work because `http://domain/folder/NEEDTHIS` uses "/" even if DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is "\". Use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for files: `C:\folder\folder` on Win or `//Volumes/Disk/Folder` on OsX

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Use [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to get simple one-liner that works both for URL and normal dir-paths. Works too, if no file is specified in path (or when path ends at dir).

```
$path = 'http://example.com/root/one/two/three/four.xml';

echo end(explode('/',dirname($path)));
```

Outputs:

```
three
```

You can replace `$path` with anything.

Comment: @Raptor have you tested it, or you just "doubt" blindly? Go on, test it -_-

Comment: my bad, but PHP documentation does not mention it supports URL.

Comment: PHP documentation doesn't mention many things. Simple `dirname()` of url gives this: `http://example.com/root/one/two/three`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://domain/folder/folder2/folderanother/NEEDTHIS/filename.xml";
$array = explode('/',$url);
$count = count($array);
echo $array[$count-2];
```